# Перевод из любой СС в любую. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

Здравствуйте. Я написал код для перевода из любой сс в любую (до 16). Но мне нужно еще добавить условие чтобы, при начилии любого числа в 2ой сс он выдавал ошибку а не переводил. Я написал условие но оно почему то не хочет нормально работать, буду благодарен если поможете исправить и дополнить.

```
for (i = 0; i < st.length(); i++)

            if (ss1 < 10 && st[i] >= ss1)
            {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
```

Это для любой сс < 10. Помогите пожалуйста сделать еще и для 11..16.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int i, dec, k, p, ss1, ss2;
    string st, hex;
    string digits[16] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

    cout << "chislo" << endl;
    cin >> st;  
    cout << "ss1" << endl;
    cin >> ss1;
    cout << "ss2" << endl;
    cin >> ss2;

    for (i = 0; i < st.length(); i++)

        if (ss1 < 10 && st[i] >= ss1)
        {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }

    dec = 0;
    p = st.length() - 1;

    for (i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(st[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(ss1,p);
        } 

    do 
        { 
        hex.insert(0, digits[dec % ss2]); 
        dec /= ss2; 
        } while (dec != 0); 

    cout << hex << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Напиши тесты вначале. Не знаю, что у тебя там понаписано в коде, но проверка ввода двоичного числа делается очень просто: а) `strspn()` + `strlen()`, б) `strtoull()`, и никакого C++ не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, ваша проверка `st[i] >= ss1` работает неверно, так как сравнивает символ не с символом, а с числом...

Я бы сделал так:

```
if (toupper(st[i]) >= digits[ss1-1][0])
{
    cout << "Error" << endl;
```

Только это проверка полагается на то, что у вас ввод только из цифр и указанных букв.

Кстати, зачем у вас `digits` - массив строк? куда удобне было бы работать с

```
char digins[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Основной цикл перевода строки в десятичное число я бы переписал без `pow`:

```
for (i = st.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    k = toupper(st[i]);
    dec = dec*10 + ((k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') ;
}
```

Да и с выводом... По-моему, проще было бы сделать строку обратную, а потом развернуть, скажем. По крайней мере, куда эффективнее, чем возня с `insert`.

**Update** Готовое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    unsigned int maxRadix = digits.length();

    string value;
    unsigned int from, to;
    cout << "Enter number from_radix to_radix: ";
    cin >> value >> from >> to;

    if (from < 2 || from > maxRadix || to < 2 || to > maxRadix)
    {
        cerr << "Wronf radix(es)\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = digits.find(tolower(value[i]));
        if (pos == string::npos || pos > from)
        {
            cerr << "Wrong symbol in value " << value << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    unsigned long long number = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < value.length(); ++i)
    {
        char k = tolower(value[i]);
        number = number*from + ((k>='a') ? k-'a' + 10 : k-'0');
    }

    cout << "Decimal: " << number << endl;

    string result;
    while(number)
    {
        result.push_back(digits[number%to]);
        number /= to;
    }
    for(int i = 0, j = result.length()-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        char x = result[i];
        result[i] = result[j];
        result[j] = x;
    }

    cout << result << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но почему то не работает) Я еще попытался сделать так: if (toupper(st[i]) >= digits[ss1-1][0]+'0') но все равно не выходит. Если ss1 < ss2 всегда при вашем варианте выдает Error а при моем просто не выдает никогда)

Comment: Возможно, я где-то и ошибся, я же его не компилировал, так, давал идеи, к которым надо относиться критически :) Вот, смотрите готовый вариант программы в ответе...